# Split API output into two columns

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create two column footer menu from API get request. This code outputs category items with one column. I want make it two columns, **if category items are more than four, those category items should goes to second column**.

**ajax-script.php**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery.when( jQuery.ajax({
                url: config_lymited_home + 'api/category-pages/filter/included-in-buy-menu',
                crossDomain: true,
                async: true,
                cache:false,
                type: 'GET',
            })).then(function (footerlink) {

              if (footerlink[0].data.length > 0) {
                  if((footerlink[0].data > 0) && (footerlink[0].data < 4)) {
                    $.each(footerlink[0].data, function (k, row) {
                        $('#footerlink').append('<li><a class="footer-links" href=' + config_lymited_home + 'type/' + row.slug + '/buy' + '>' + row.name + '</a></li>');
                    });
                }
             else {
                $.each(footersecondrow[0].data, function (k, row) {
                    $('#footersecondrow').append('<li><a class="footer-links" href=' + config_lymited_home + 'type/' + row.slug + '/buy' + '>' + row.name + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        }
      });
  });
```

**footer.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 footer-links">
 <ul id="footerlink"></ul>
 <ul id="footersecondrow"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to place your `else` statement inside your first `if` clause and then call `footerlink[0].data` instead of `footerescondrow[0].data` because `footersecondrow` is never defined.

```
if (footerlink[0].data.length > 0) {
  if ((footerlink[0].data > 0) && (footerlink[0].data < 4)) {
    $.each(footerlink[0].data, function(k, row) {
      $('#footerlink').append('<li><a class="footer-links" href=' + config_lymited_home + 'type/' + row.slug + '/buy' + '>' + row.name + '</a></li>');
    });
  } 
  else {
    $.each(footerlink[0].data, function(k, row) {
      $('#footersecondrow').append('<li><a class="footer-links" href=' + config_lymited_home + 'type/' + row.slug + '/buy' + '>' + row.name + '</a></li>');
    });
  }
}
```

You can add separate columns in your PHP file to get the split columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 footer-links">
       <ul id="footerlink"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 footer-links">
       <ul id="footersecondrow"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with this. But it also outputs category items in a single column. - @Andrew Halpern